# Node freeze after a specific route call

Tags: express, mongoose

I use node as my REST API for a bit and now I'm stuck with this simple function

What I want: save new record newM and it does, after save check if the year collection contains the year and if not save a new one and it does.

this is the route in test/debug mode

```
router.post('/addnew', (req, res, next) => {
    let newM = new Var(req.body.obj);
    newM.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(1, err); // TODO test
        const newObjYear = new Date(req.body.obj.date).getFullYear();
        console.log(newObjYear); // TODO test
        NewsYear.findOne({year: newObjYear}, (err, year) => {
            if (err) return console.log(2, err); // TODO test
            if (!year) {
                const newYearM = new NewsYear({
                    year: newObjYear
                });
                newYearM.save( err => {if (err) return console.log(3, err);});
                console.log('save'); // TODO test
            }
            if (year) {
                console.log('year'); // TODO test
            }
            console.log('last'); // TODO test
            res.status(200).json({ok:'ok'});
            next(); // TODO test
        });
    });
});
```

this is the console

```
2021
save
last
POST /api-admin-news/addnew 200 30.853 ms - 11
```

like it supposes to, but after this node not responding to nothing and based on CPU usage drop after stop, Node is in some infinite loop.
Other routes, even in this route-model like findByIdAndUpdate with the same code works fine.
I switch to WebStorm recently and in the debug mode (not expert) nothing different found

```
node -v : v10.10.0
"mongoose": "^5.1.1",
"express": "~4.16.0",
```

now Working on Windows, tested on ubuntu with pm2 and nginx and the same result.

Sorry for the English :D

thanks
EDIT1: removed a wrong copied part of code

Comment: the next() is for test mode, but nothing changed when added

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in one schema.post('save')

testing the code I ended with only save func

```
let odg = new Var(req.body.obj);
odg.save( );
res.status(200).json({ok:'ok'});
```

and still has the same problem.

so I looked at the Schema file and try to comment part by part and ended with one line that makes the problem.

hope that I can help someone else with the same problem